# Getting Wifi RSSI Values continuously Android Application Doesn't start

Tags: android, wifi, android-wifi

I wrote an Android application to get wifi rssi values without connecting to wifi networks.

here is the code

```
package com.affno.wifirssichecker;

import android.content.Context;
import android.net.wifi.ScanResult;
import android.net.wifi.WifiManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.TextView;

import static com.affno.wifirssichecker.R.id.RSSI;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

TextView rssiView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    rssiView = (TextView)findViewById(RSSI);

    WifiManager wifi = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    ScanResult result0 = (ScanResult) wifi.getScanResults();
    String ssid = result0.SSID;
    int rssi = result0.level;
    String rssiString0 = String.valueOf(rssi);
    rssiView.setText("\n" + ssid + "   " + rssiString0);
}
}
```

But when I deployed this app into my android device the application won't start. just pop up and then vanished. I can't figure out what is the problem. can anyone help me.

But I noticed that there are several wifi networks in the area which I tested this app. Is the problem occur because of that?

What i want is to check RSSI values of every Wifi network with the SSID or MAC Continuously around my area.

And I want to know if there is anyway that I Can do that?

Comment: any stack trace? error log?

Comment: no errors just start and collapse application without doing anything. maybe the problem is in the scanresult permissions. I don't know exactly still trying to figure out

Comment: on which device, which Android version are you doing this?

Comment: Please post your android logcat, while you open the app.

Comment: Sorry I don't know how to get the logcat. And the app window appear and disappear instantly.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't find an exact solution. But I figure out what is the problem. I used an android device which run on Android version 6.0 .  So as of Android 6.0 permission behavior has changed to runtime.

So in this case I need permission to Scan Wifi Networks. So I need to check if the permission is granted previously. If yes, we can run the application if not the app will crash. But Couldn't find exactly a proper way to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to get the wifi and location permissions.in Android Marshmallow and above you need to get this permission at run time.

here is my code!!
Mainifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.wifi">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
</manifest>`
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.wifi;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.net.wifi.ScanResult;
import android.net.wifi.WifiManager;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private WifiManager mwifiManager;

private List<ScanResult> results;
private ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

private int REQUEST_PERMISSION_CODE = 1;

private String[] Permissions = {Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
                                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
                                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE,
                                Manifest.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE};

boolean start ;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button scan_btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);


    scan_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            scan_wifi();
        }
    });

}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    requestPermissions();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    scan_wifi();
}

private void scan_wifi(){
    if(start){
        mwifiManager = (WifiManager) 
getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        if (!mwifiManager.isWifiEnabled()) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "WIFI DISABLED", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            mwifiManager.setWifiEnabled(true);
        }

        registerReceiver(wifireceiver,new 
IntentFilter(WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION));
        mwifiManager.startScan();
        Toast.makeText(this,"SCANING",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    else {
        /* GET RUN TIME PERMISSION*/
        requestPermissions();

    }
}

private void requestPermissions() {
    if (    (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Permissions[0]) != 
PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)||
            (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Permissions[1]) != 
PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)||
            (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Permissions[2]) != 
PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)||
            (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Permissions[3]) != 
PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)) {

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Permissions[0],
                                                                    Permissions[1],
                                                                    Permissions[2],
                                                                    Permissions[3]},
                                            REQUEST_PERMISSION_CODE);

    } else {
        //Toast.makeText(this, "Permission alredy granted", 
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        start = true;
    }
}

BroadcastReceiver wifireceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        TextView tx = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        tx.setText("WIFI LIST \n");

        results = mwifiManager.getScanResults();
        unregisterReceiver(this);

        results = mwifiManager.getScanResults();
        Log.d("Wifi", String.valueOf(results.size()));
        for (ScanResult res : results) {
            tx.append("SSID :" +res.SSID + "Capblt :" + res.capabilities+ "\n");

        }

    }
};


@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] 
grantResults) {

    if(requestCode == REQUEST_PERMISSION_CODE){
        if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == 
PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Permission granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            start = true;

        }
        else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Permission not granted", 
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            start = false;
        }
    }
    }





}
```